# Bug? When debugging with Pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'd like to know if anybody else has the same problem as me when using this IDE.

What happens is that once I have put my breakpoints and I click over the Debug icon, the IDE opens automatically another tab with my .py file, so I have open 2 identical tabs just because I want to debug.

This is a pain since when I stop the debugger the tab is still open and, if I forget to close it, and I modify the code, then I have 2 different codes for the same file, and PyCharm explodes with some weird errors.

Help?!

Comment: You should post your question on the editor support site: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to know either this is the normal behavior of this IDE and I realized recently, or it's a bug that affects more people than me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyCharm opens old versions or files in duplicate tabs while debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042034/pycharm-opens-old-versions-or-files-in-duplicate-tabs-while-debugging)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23042034/1292652