# PyCharm opens old versions or files in duplicate tabs while debugging

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, filesystemwatcher

When I try to debug a Python file with PyCharm Community Edition, the IDE opens a new tab (highlighted in yellow) despite me having that file open already in a pre-existing tab.

Sometimes, that duplicate tab contains an older version of the file without changes that I just made.

Although both of the above are different issues and don't always occur together, I suspect there's a common cause. How can I disable these non-intuitive behaviours?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The problem is apparently similar to the cause of this question I edited during my search: [Make PyCharm alert to reload files when they're changed externally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21175677/129265). Another person that seems to be facing the same issue got an answer here: [Bug? When debugging with Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883305/bug-when-debugging-with-pycharm).

**I had opened a directory that was inside a symlink to another directory**. (I link core folders like Pictures, Downloads and Workspaces placed in my Dropbox folder in my Home folder on Ubuntu).

That explains the duplicate tab issue, and probably is also responsible for the mismatch in the files. Opening the same folder by its true path resolved the issue (or so it seems for now).

Comment: This can also happen if you create a PyCharm project by following a symlink. The debugger will open files via their absolute paths while normal editor access will open then via their symlink path.  If you hit a break point and step into another file it will have a yellow highlighted tab. If you attempt to make changes to the source you will get a dialog that says "These files do not belong to the project" and ask if you want to unlock them. Opening/creating projects from existing sources by following absolute paths, not symlinks avoids the issue.

Comment: this is not a solution of course, just a workaround that ignores the problem

Comment: 2023, July: I just ran into this, and this still happens with PyCharm 2023.1.3. This answer is still valid. TL;DR - Always open your PyCharm project via the absolute path.

Comment: 2023. I still don't answer what the solution is...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a windows system. I have no idea why but creating a new script in the same directory and cutting and pasteing the entire program there fixed it.

Note: in case it matters I'm using pycharm community edition